# Как хранить значения парметров в PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Для примера к вопросу лучше всего подойдет XML-файл (YML-файл), который используется для выгрузки товаров в Яндекс Маркет. Там внутри есть параметры к товарному предложению: высота товара, вес, и прочие. Так вот, значения этих параметров либо числа, либо строки, либо наборы (строка с перечислением)... Как хранить эти значения в таблице если они учавствуют в поиске? Например, если мы все значения будем рассматривать как строки, то как сравнивать числа в строковом представлении? Подскажите куда копать или может кто-то решал уже такие задачи и подскажет решение этой проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача слишком общая.

Примерно так: ключевые параметры в обычных колонках, не ключевые в [jsonb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html).

Или всё, кроме идентификатора, в jsonb, не структурируя особо; индексы можно построить и по последовательности ключей. Тут дело в [имеющихся навыках](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) и предпочтениях.

А можно всё хранить в [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/hstore.html), разница не велика. Или даже в [xml](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-xml.html), если кругом враги и xml рулит.

Answer (score -1):

Есть еще альтернативный вариант в виде EAV структуры, причем расширенной:
name, value_int, value_money, value_string.